# aes encryption implementation

Tags: c++, c, aes

For some reason my AES encryption implementation cannot parse/encrypt/decrypt over about 100byte amount of data.

Whenever I encrypt and decrypt above say 100byte it doesn't complete the rest that comes after about those bytes.

I use the same method to encrypt. But above 100byte it comes out all wrong for whatever reason.

I cannot figure out why. Maybe someone else can tell me how to fix it.

Comment: please indent your code correctly before posting

Answer (score 6):

hint: strlen, strcat, str... all use null termination to determine the end of data, that means your real data cannot have embedded 0s.

Comment: I deleted the last 0 terminator but that didn't do it.

Comment: I think what he was getting at is that your data probably has embedded null characters in it.  Does it, or is it strictly text?

Comment: your encrypted data cannot contain 0s either. check where n came from.

Comment: n is the size of the input text.